# Windows 10 IoT Core will not install onto my SD card / Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, microsoft-windows-iot

I tried to install Windows 10 IoT Core onto my SD card using Microsoft's IoT Dashboard. I fill out all of the fields then it says:

> Downloading Windows IoT Core
>   Download Complete.

Then it says:

> Flashing your SD card
>   Unpacking installer

Then a window pops up saying:

> Windows Installer. Version 5.0.15063.0
>   Msiexec /option  [Optional Parameter]

Then it goes into detail about the options for the parameters.
Then after I push ok a new window pops up saying:

> Failed to unpack the Windows 10 IoT Core Installation Package.

What's the issue here, and how can I fix this?

Comment: is size of your SD card the same as recomended?

Comment: What exactly is recommended

Comment: at least 8 GB in size, and at a minimum Class 10 SD card

Comment: It is a 32 GB but I dont know abour the class

Answer (score 4):

Look what [1] tells:

> **Troubleshooting Install issues**
>
> Error: Failed to unpack Windows 10 IoT
>
> Core installation package
> If your installation fails with the above message then you need to run the setup.exe using the Administrator account. This error message could appear even if you are logged in as a user who has administrator rights; it has to be the Administrator user.

also there is a note:

> Please note that by default the Administrator account is disable in Windows 10.

and there are instructions how to enable them.

[1] http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/104/install-windows-10-iot.html